# Left outer join off of group by dataset using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am attempting to write the following SQL as a linq query.

```
SELECT grp.OrganisationId,
       grp.OrderCount,
       organisations.Name
FROM   (select OrganisationId,
               count(*) as OrderCount
        from orders
        where 1 = 1
        group by OrganisationId) grp
LEFT OUTER JOIN organisations on grp.OrganisationId = organisations.OrganisationId
WHERE 1 = 1
```

The where clauses are simplified for the benefit of the example.

I need to do this without the use of navigational properties.

This is my attempt:

```
var organisationQuery = ClientDBContext.Organisations.Where(x => true);

var orderGrouped = from order in ClientDBContext.Orders.Where(x => true)
group order by order.OrganisationId into grouping
select new { Id = grouping.Key.Value, OrderCount = grouping.Count() };

var orders = from og in orderGrouped
join org in organisationQuery on og.Id equals org.Id
select(x => new OrganisationOrdersReportPoco()
{
    OrganisationNameThenCode = org.Name,
    TotalOrders = og.OrderCount
});
```

But I am getting an error of...

Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'

From previous threads, I believe this is because I have "lost the join with order" (but I don't understand why that matters when I am creating a new recordset of Organisation, Count).

Thanks!

*I understand you may believe navigation properties are the solution here, but if possible, please can we keep the discussion to the join off of the group by as this is the question I am trying to resolve.*

Comment: The reason you don't want to use navigationproperties is that theres no direct foreignkey relationship between these 2 entities?

Comment: No, there is. Order holds organisation Id... but it is just really slow. I only want the organisations with orders, and I can't see a way (using nav props) of implementing a group by approach (by far the most efficient approach, based on my data). If I do a "where .any()" or similar, it is taking forever to run.

Comment: The reason for this may be because you pull the data before you process it because you have 3 queries and i doubt linq 2 entities is that smart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing `lambda` and `LINQ` expressions. Change select to:

```
select new OrganisationOrdersReportPoco()
{
    OrganisationNameThenCode = org.Name,
    TotalOrders = og.OrderCount
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your model correctly you could try this instead:

```
var orders = ClientDBContext.Organisations.Select(org => new OrganisationOrdersReportPoco
{
    OrganisationNameThenCode = org.Name,
    TotalOrders = org.Orders.Count()
}).ToList();
```